# Android Intent-filter not registered using android:scheme on some devices

Tags: android, intentfilter, url-scheme

My android app should interact with our web site doing some streaming. If the user does not have the app installed we provide a webpage informing about the app and link to download it.

The info page is located at: http://my.site.no/android

And all the links are prefixed with this info page: http://my.site.no/android?url=http://something.to.stream

In the app I have declared the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="my.site.no" android:pathPrefix="/android" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

This works for most devices.. but some (especially Samsung Galaxy SIII’s) refuses to register this intent filter. Even though the app is installed the user always lands on the info page. This is not just happening on the standard browser but also with other browsers like firefox and chrome on the same device. There is no “default app” settings active on the devices which refuses to register the intent.

Any idea what might be wrong ? Or how to try to debug this to find the cause ?

Comment: It also looks like Dolphin Browser don't send intents when url's are cliced. The app is not triggered on my HTC Desire using Dolphin, but works nicely on the native browser.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to register another for the scheme "https". I had this problem with some apps and this solved it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did not solve our issue unfortunately. I can mention that the raw url (http://my.site.no/android?url=http://something.to.stream) clicked on from gmail triggers the app on those devices. So it’s something with the browsers and http/https schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. In my case, it was caused by the activity accidentally having set

```
android:exported="false"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml. It seems that some devices/Android versions respect this flag and some don't. In my case, it worked on a HTC Sensation (Android 4.0.3), but not on a HTC One X (Android 4.1.1) or a Samsung Galaxy S III (Android 4.1.2).